# Tablulate all the columns of a dataframe and their corresponding column indices in R

Tags: r, indexing, multiple-columns, lapply

My sample data is as follows:

```
structure(list(v1 = 1:4, v2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L), v3 = 1:4, v4 = c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I would like to get a table with the column names and their indices. E.g.

```
v1  v2  v3
1   2   3
```

I tried the following codes (after searching over the various forums and internet but it always return NA or some errors)

```
> lapply(df, function(x) match(x, names(df)))
$v1
[1] NA NA NA NA

$v2
[1] NA NA NA NA

$v3
[1] NA NA NA NA

$v4
[1] NA NA NA NA

> lapply(df, function(x) which(colnames(df)==x))
$v1
integer(0)

$v2
integer(0)

$v3
integer(0)

$v4
integer(0)
```

Thank you very much for your time and effort in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
aa <- 1:ncol(iris)       ## create vector of indices of the right size
names(aa) <- names(iris) ## name entries
aa
```

Comment: Or `setNames(seq_len(ncol(dat)), colnames(dat))`